# How to do error messages in symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I have used CRUD to generate actions for an entity. However, I would like to modify the edit action; for instance, a user select 'inactive' represented by 1 for State then they will be shown an error message otherwise they can proceed to updating that row. Within the entity these are the variables `state`, `paypid`, `startDate`, `endDate`.

This is what the edit action currently looks like.

```
 public function editAction($Paypid)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('comtwclagripayrollBundle:Payrollperiod')
        ->findBy(['paypid' => $Paypid, 'state' => 0]);

    if (!$entity) {
        $this->addFlash(
        'notice',
        'You cannot edit an inactive Payroll Period'
        );

        return $this->redirectToRoute('/payrollperiod');
    }

    $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($Paypid);

    return array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    );        
}

And this method in the repository entity.

public function findByPaypidAndActiveState($Paypid)
{
    return $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery(
            'SELECT p FROM comtwclagripayrollBundle:Payrollperiod 
                WHERE paypid = :paypid AND state = :state'
        )
        ->setParameter('paypid', $Paypid)
        ->setParameter('state', 0)
        ->getResult();
}
```

Comment: Can you clearify what exactly triggers the error? If selecting a specific value inside the form, it's best to handle this with custom validation (see http://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html), but if you want the whole action to be unusable when the user has a specific state, that's probably best handled by the security layer. Finally you can always create custom 'flash messages' as errors and simply not allow use of the form in certain cases.. please describe further what you want to achieve in detail.

Comment: When the user selects an inactive state to edit it should give them an error message saying that this state can't be edited. I have added something like this.

Comment: A flash like you have is an OK solution, right? What more do you need?

Comment: i have an error at the addflash becuase i dont think it was done correctly. That's where I need the help

Comment: Is there something else that is needed. like in the twig

Comment: The error message is not outputted but it redirects to the page. How do I get the error message to be outputted?? Thanks in advance for any assistance given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe add to view something like this(only for twig template):

```
{% for type, flash_messages in app.session.flashBag.all %}                    
      {% for flash_message in flash_messages %}
              {{ flash_message }}
       {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I recomended right bechind `<body>` tag.

Comment: no problem, so mark my answear as usefull for others